# Как правильно позиционировать элементы данные внизу

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтоб Block1 всегда был слева, Block2 всегда посередине блока header,Block3 под блоком Block2,а Block 4 всегда слева, но Block4 может и не быть

```
<div class="header" style="background: rgb(90, 176, 203);"><div class="Block1">Блок1</div>
<div class="header-wrapper">
<span class="Block2">Block2</span>
<span class="Block3">Block3</span>
<span class="Block4">Block4</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, но это не лучшее решение через абсолютно спозиционированные элементы

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.column {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header__block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fefefe;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__block--1 {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.header__block--2 {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.header__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.header__block--3 {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.header__block--4 {
  background-color: darkorchid;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header__block--1 header__block">1</div>
    <div class="header__block--4 header__block">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__wrapper">
    <div class="header__block--2 header__block">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__wrapper">
    <div class="header__block--3 header__block">3</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```